# GWT removeHandler on first event notification

Tags: java, events, gwt, event-handling

I want to remove a GWT event handler the first time I receive an event. I also want to avoid polluting my class with tracking registration objects that aren't really necessary. I currently have it coded as:

```
final HandlerRegistration[] registrationRef = new HandlerRegistration[1];
registrationRef[0] = dialog.addFooHandler(new FooHandler()
{
    public void onFoo(FooEvent event)
    {
        HandlerRegistration removeMe = registrationRef[0];
        if(removeMe != null)
        {
            removeMe.removeHandler();
        }

        // do stuff here
    }
});
```

but the use of registrationRef makes the code less readable. Is there a better way to do this without adding variables to my class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd just make the `HandlerRegistration` object a field of the enclosing class, that way you won't be bothered by the compiler and it's more "elegant" than shuffling arrays and stuff:

```
public class TestWidget extends Composite {
    //...

    HandlerRegistration handler;

    public TestWidget() {
        // ...

        handler = button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // ...
                handler.removeHandler();                
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess this is the way to go when you only have one of these listeners in a class (things get more messy when you have an arbitrary number of widgets you're treating this way though). I was hoping there was a way to do this without adding a new field. Oh well...

Comment: This may not be as straight forward as it seems. I have case where the handler is set to null in the onXXX() method. Why? Because there is nothing to stop GWT from calling the handler straight away. For example, in the IE case in Image.onLoad(), if the image is already loaded it can call the handler actually during the addLoadHandler() call. I found in that case the only fix was to wrap in a "if null" check, then cleanup later.

Comment: This doesn't work if the handler can be added multiple times.